# Why would a socket in use exception be thrown for TcpClient(IPEndPoint) but not TcpClient(String, Int32)?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, localhost, windows-10

Why would a socket in use exception be thrown for [TcpClient(IPEndPoint)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bsb3c8f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but not [TcpClient(String, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/115ytk56%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

I have in my code a listener that I use with (ip is ::1, port is 12345)

```
listener = new TcpListener(ip, port); //create listener
listener.Start(); //start listener
//now code will wait at the while loop until someone connects.
while (listener.Pending()) { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); } //check for pending connections every second.
client = listener.AcceptTcpClient(); //when incoming connection is found accept it.
```

Note that code is inside a `Task listenerTask = Task.Run(() =>{});`

in another task I have the following

```
//client = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint(ip, port)); //does not work
client = new TcpClient("localhost", port); //localhost resolves to ::1
```

So what's the deal? What is the difference? Am I wrong about localhost resolving to ::1? If it doesn't resolve to that then how can my program echo back on itself?

I will try to get more information in the meantime.

Exception details:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException was unhandled
ErrorCode=10048
HResult=-2147467259
Message=Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
NativeErrorCode=10048
Source=System
StackTrace:
     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
     at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(IPEndPoint localEP)
     at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Connector(IPAddress[] ips, Int32 port)
```

Comment: looks like you are trying to use the same port again which is not permitted.

Comment: In the Resource Monitor I am seeing my ConsoleApplication1.exe with two entries (when it is working). One entry has local port 12345 and remote port 63123, while the other entry has local port 63123 and remote port 12345. @Rahul is this what you are talking about?

Comment: not much sure but try using different port altogether.

Comment: It isn't connecting if I use a different port. On MSDN I noticed [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that for `IPEndPoint` it says it binds it to the _local_ endpoint. While for `str, int` it says it connects to the port on the _host_. This wording makes me feel like it isn't even trying to connect. I will make some changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code of:

```
client = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint(ip, port));
```

Binds the *local* port with the *local* IP address for *later* use.

Once knowing this I was able to change my code to the following and it works how I intended it to:

```
client = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint(localIp, localPort)); //sets up how we are going to be connecting.
client.Connect(remoteIp, remotePort); //does the real connecting.
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx