# TcpClient with IPEndPoint fails, but TcpClient with same IPEndPoint.Address does not?

Tags: .net-core, tcpclient, socketexception

I got a weird situation here, not sure if its a bug in .NET Core or my brain.

using IPEndPoint to store the destination IP:port in my class, I use a TcpClient to connect.

```
IPEndPoint _ipendpoint = IPEndPoint.Parse("127.0.0.1:5000");
TcpClient tcp1 = new TcpClient(_ipendpoint);
Tcpclient tcp2 = new TcpClient(_ipendpoint.Address.ToString(), _ipendpoint.Port);
```

tcp1 gives `SocketException`, tcp2 does not. (comment one out to test the other)

So whats the deal here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it. So much NOT understandable why MS implemented it this way.

Answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199556/why-would-a-socket-in-use-exception-be-thrown-for-tcpclientipendpoint-but-not)

In short words: while they seem to be equal (both provide an address and port) one connects TO the address as client, the other binds to the address (opens the port on the local machine).

This doesnt get really clear from the MSDN documentation. Also, would you expect TcpClient to act as server? Bad, bad design decicions.